# how to get copied text from clipboard on Golang [Mac]

Tags: go, clipboard

first of all I'm beginner of Golang

I wonder how to get copied text from clipboard on GoLang

I've searched about three packages but I don't know the way yet

```
"github.com/atotto/clipboard"
"github.com/d-tsuji/clipboard"
"golang.design/x/clipboard"
```

I just want to get copied text like this

```
this is python code

copy_string = pyperclip.paste()
```

help me guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will depend on your OS. That is why packages you mention have `_unix.go` `_windows.go` `_darwing.go` etc.

There is no copy function from std lib if that is your question!

On mac, there are two function available to you:
`pbpaste` and `pbcopy`.

So if you want to copy/paste on mac without a library:

```
func copy(content string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command("pbcopy")
    in, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, err := in.Write([]byte(content)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := in.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return cmd.Wait()
}


func paste() (content string, err error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("pbpaste")
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    return string(out), err
}
```

Comment: now I wanna copy text without "cmd+c" is there a way to do that? I tried your copy func but nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm looking for
I hope this code will help someone like me

```
import "github.com/d-tsuji/clipboard"

text, err := clipboard.Get()
fmt.Println(text)
```